# How To insert an image at cursor position full screen mode in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

The follwing code works in normal mode.

```
var ed = tinyMCE.get('txt_area_id');                // get editor instance
var range = ed.selection.getRng();                  // get range
var newNode = ed.getDoc().createElement ( "img" );  // create img node
newNode.src="sample.jpg";                           // add src attribute
range.insertNode(newNode);                          // insert Node
```

but i want to insert image at cursor position full screen mode in tinymce.please help me

Comment: what happens in full screen mode? can you provide a live example (tinymce.fiddle)?

Comment: Default its working fine in normal mode when i switch to the full screen mode it always insert the image in the starting position that mean top of the editor area.

Comment: is the caret position in this case at the starting position too? (a live example really would help)